# CSS not applying in production, Angular 12 with Tailwind

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

When building my angular 12 solution for production, styles are not applied. Following online docs I have taken the following steps:

I have
`"styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ]`
in my angular.json file, and in styles.scss I import tailwind:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

In my tailwind.config.js I have:

```
module.export = {
    purge: {
        enabled: true,
        content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"]
    },
    ...
}
```

but styles are still not applied. What else do I need to do to get styles to apply correctly?

Comment: Try adding scss files here.
content: ['./src/**/*.{html,scss,ts}'],

Comment: Huhu any news does it helps ? i tried the ViewEncapsulation to NONE . but when purge is enabled to true the style file is only 800 bytes and no styles after build are applied , when i disable the purge the css is 4 mb :(